# Twilio failing to validate the request from webhooks

Tags: twilio

I am unable to validate a Twilio post or get request. Please find the my code piece below and help me to correct it accordingly.

```java
public ResponseEntity<String> businessHolidays(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestparams) {
           Map<String,String> tempParams = new HashMap<>();
    return getStringResponseEntity(request,tempParams);
}

private ResponseEntity<String> getStringResponseEntity(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestparams) {
    ValidateSignature(request, requestparams);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Succesful response", HttpStatus.OK);
}

public static void ValidateSignature(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> ivrReuestParams) {
    RequestValidator requestValidator = new RequestValidator("my authtoken");
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString().replace("http", "https"));
    System.out.println(requestValidator.validate(request.getRequestURL().toString().replace("http", "https"), ivrReuestParams, request.getHeader("X-Twilio-Signature")));    
}
```

It always returns me `false` on the validation. Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: You have this tagged as php. I think this code might be Java? There is a random `enter code here Map<String,String>` in there. Does the code on your computer have the "my authtoken" part replaced with an actual token. Can you include the code for the RequestValidator class or is that a part of the twilio library?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it MR.Me,i apologize for the "enter code here snippet" and incorrect php tag.yes  myauthtoken is actually replaced by my original auth token.yep requestValidator is from twilio SDK.